# parallax with css3 animation not working

Tags: jquery, parallax

I have a question about parallax with an animated image(with css3)

In this example the ball scrolls with background image(slower than background image), but the penguin doesn't scroll (animated).

http://jsfiddle.net/ruP8p/24/

```
.hi {
    width: 50px;
    height: 72px;
    background-image: url("http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/9/9fVQoLD.png");
    margin: 0 auto;

    -webkit-animation: wink .8s steps(10, end) infinite;
    -moz-animation: wink .8s steps(10, end) infitive;
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.